# IDrawable mouse event

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, maui

I have simple canvas that create one red line

xaml

```
 <ContentPage.Resources>
        <drawable:GraphicsDrawable  x:Key="drawable" />
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <GraphicsView Drawable="{StaticResource drawable}"/>
```

cs

```
public class GraphicsDrawable : IDrawable
{
    public void Draw(ICanvas canvas, RectF dirtyRect)
    {
        canvas.StrokeColor = Colors.Red;
        canvas.StrokeSize = 6;
        canvas.DrawLine(10, 10, 99999, 10000);
        canvas.FillColor = Colors.Red;
    }
}
```

But how can I implement mouse event? Basically I want to get coordinates of place on canvas where I clicked how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can  track your touch position inside the scene with SkiaSharp in xamarin:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/skiasharp?view=skiasharp-2.80.2

check the document under to know how to deal with touch: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/transforms/touch

Comment: Thank you for your response. But its maui actaully is there anything to handle click there?

Comment: maui can do what xamarin can do , there will have more document about it in the future though.